# Replace Dataframe column name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe with below columns:

```
'TERRITORY', 'FIELD OF STUDY', 'SELECT YEAR T (ACADEMIC YEAR = T-1  OR  T)', 'VALUE'
```

I want to replace `"YEAR"` if dataframe column name contains `"SELECT YEAR"`. How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple solution is use list comprehension:

```
df.columns = ["YEAR" if "SELECT YEAR" in x else x for x in df.columns]
```

Pandas solution:

```
df.columns = df.columns.where(~df.columns.str.contains('SELECT YEAR'), 'YEAR')
```

Only be careful if multiple values was setting, then problem with selecting, because:

```
print (df['YEAR'])
```

return all columns `YEAR`.

**Sample**:

```
c = ['SELECT YEAR  d', 'FIELD OF STUDY', 'SELECT YEAR T (ACADEMIC YEAR = T-1  OR  T)', 'VALUE']
df = pd.DataFrame(0, columns=c, index=[1,2])

df.columns = ["YEAR" if "SELECT YEAR" in x else x for x in df.columns]
print (df)
   YEAR  FIELD OF STUDY  YEAR  VALUE
1     0               0     0      0
2     0               0     0      0

print (df['YEAR'])
   YEAR  YEAR
1     0     0
2     0     0
```